# Problema al usar preg_match

Tags: php

Hola quiero obtener el titulo de una pagina de un link 
codigo

```
<?php
$holas = file_get_contents('https://www.frikipandi.com/');
$stra = '/<title>(.*)</title>/i';
preg_match($stra, $holas, $titulo);
echo $titulo[1];?>
```

Error:

> Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 't' in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que funcione necesitas escapar el simbolo `/` con `\` asi:

```
<?php
$holas = file_get_contents('https://www.frikipandi.com/');
$stra = '/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i';
preg_match($stra, $holas, $titulo);
echo $titulo[1];
?>
```